# including controllers in Symfony2 issue

Tags: symfony

I am beginner at symfony and I've been confused about couple things, well my website has a header where user can search,select language and manage his account and i have a navigation menu and a footer that is common between all my website pages , so i created a commonbundle where i put the common code for header and menu and footer i also created a global layout where i included my header controller,menu controller and footer controller, i don't know if this approach is correct and im already having problem about how to do following stuff:

1. include the search bundle in my header
2. get the current request in header as it returns a subrequest
3. generate url in my header because i have no route for it as it doesn't suppose to have one because we'll never call it .

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more what do you want? For example, in the 1. point, you want to render a header? Or what do you mean like search bundle? In the header, you want to have access to the main Request? You have to pass it to your header render function. What you mean like generate url? For that, in twig there is the url() or path() functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to help with setting up fragments:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework

As for getting the top level request, try:

```
$this->container->get('request');
```

Answer (score 0):

i did a search about it and found that : you cannot redirect from an embedded controller as we only get the response content. With the current architecture, I don't think it is even possible and anyway, I'm not sure we want to support this feature.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2517